# Combine sound such as MP3 to video MOV in OS X?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, adobe

I need to combine a movie without sounds and a MP3 file. How can I do it in OS X? I have Adobe After Effects but it is not at all intuitive to use -- or better I need to find some button to render the sounds with the movie but now no time -- is there some easy fast-to-use software for OS X to combine sounds and videos?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

iMovie is the obvious choice. It's very easy to use and fairly reasonable in price. You might have it already if you have a newish mac or else it's $15 I think.

http://www.apple.com/ilife/imovie/

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so Apple way, clever -- worked like a charm without After Effect's slow rendering. Not professional thing but works :)

Answer (score 39):

ffmpeg supports combining video and audio without re-encoding:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -i input.mp3 -c copy -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -shortest output.mov
```

`-map 0:0` means input file 0, stream 0. `-c copy` copies video and audio codecs. `-shortest` makes the combined file as long as the shorter file.

Comment: The best and fastest choice to combine or merge audio and video files without re-encoding. Really useful. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Indeed, the quickest way without extra software. I have DaVinciResolve16 for editing, Handbrake, even VLC can maybe do it, but this was a simple quest, thank you a lot for this simple, effective and absolutely fast solution (avoiding also recompression). 
PD: this is 2020, 4 years later :) OS 10.14

Comment: Thanks for the excellent answer, worked in seconds for me with 30 min mp3 and mov files.

Answer (score 0):

**Adobe After Effects**

I remembered now how to do it in After Effects: `Composition > Add to Render Queue` and then click `lossless` and put the cross to the audio thing. Now specify the target and then hit `Render`.

A good video [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=46zmPFLA6Xo) how to do it.

Comment: Yet this solution is taking pretty long time do, hopefully someone able to provide a more casual way.